# El PreparedStatement se queda enganchado cuando hago muchas consultas

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statements

Tengo un método que tiene que estar constantemente enviando peticiones al servidor donde se aloja la base de datos, el lugar donde lo pruebo se conectan a internet mediante parabólica.

La función del programa es enviar un número guardando también fecha y hora al servidor cada vez que pulso un botón, el problema que tengo es que se queda enganchado cuando envío X peticiones al servidor.

Pensaba que era el método `executeUpdate()` y he puesto para ver si se arreglaba el método `setQueryTimeout(2)` para que cancele la ejecución a los 2 segundos si se queda enganchada pero no me soluciona el problema.

```
public class PanelPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private PreparedStatement pstInsert = null;
    Connection connection = null;

   /*Constructor*/
   public PanelPrincipal(){

   /*Se establece la conexión con la base de datos*/ 
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://midominio.com:3306/baseDatos", "usuario", "contraseña");

   /*Se crea el PreparedStatemnt con la consulta correspondiente*/
   pstInsert = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO registro_asistencia_empleado(id_persona, fecha, hora) VALUES (?, CURDATE(), CURTIME())");
   }

/*Este es el método que cuando pulso un botón inserto el Id de la persona que he insertado en el TextField(He omitido dicha parte para simplificar)*/
    private boolean insertarRegistro(int id_persona){            
        try  {                              
                pstInsert.setInt(1, id_persona);

                pstInsert.executeUpdate();

                return true;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {  

               Logger.getLogger(PanelPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);                        

            } 
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Quizas al usar el mismo PreparedStatement siempre te este dando problemas. Prueba a inicializarlo dentro del metodo insertaRregistro (solo pstInsert)

Comment: No se ve todo el contexto, pero por lo que se puede apreciar es posible que tengas un problema de exceso de conexiones, ya que creas la conexión a la BD en el constructor de la clase y luego no la cierras. Así que cada vez que hagas `new PanelPrincipal()` se creará una nueva conexión. O bien cierras la conexión o bien la sacas del constructor y se la pasas en parámetro al método de inserción o bien creas un polo de conexiones.

Comment: Al constructor solo lo llamo una vez, cuando inicio el programa, ya no se vuelve a llamar de nuevo. el programa lo he probado en local y funciona perfectamente y ha estado días enteros funcionando, el problema es cuando la conexión a internet es mas floja y mas inestable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema que tienes radica en que no estás cerrando ni el PreparedStatement ni la Connection cada vez que realizas la insert. Por cada vez que das click estás creando un pool nuevo de conexión manteniendo todos abiertos.

```
public class PanelPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private PreparedStatement pstInsert = null;
    Connection connection = null;

    /* Constructor */
    public PanelPrincipal() {

        /* Se establece la conexión con la base de datos */
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://midominio.com:3306/baseDatos", "usuario", "contraseña");

        /* Se crea el PreparedStatemnt con la consulta correspondiente */
        pstInsert = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO registro_asistencia_empleado(id_persona, fecha, hora) VALUES (?, CURDATE(), CURTIME())");
    }

    /*
     * Este es el método que cuando pulso un botón inserto el Id de la persona
     * que he insertado en el TextField(He omitido dicha parte para simplificar)
     */
    private boolean insertarRegistro(int id_persona) {
        /* boolean return */
        Boolean retorno = false;
        try {
            pstInsert.setInt(1, id_persona);

            pstInsert.executeUpdate();

            retorno = true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(PanelPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } finally {
            // Cerramos el PreparedStatement
            if (pstInsert != null) {
                pstInsert.close();
            }
            // Cerramos la conexión
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
            return retorno;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo el uso de try con recursos para que java gestione el .close() y no tengas que hacer tantas maniobras con el finally

Comment: Voy a prepararlo como me habeis comentado, en cuanto pueda probarlo os digo, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: He hecho lo que me has dicho y va mejor, solo que se sigue enganchando, pienso que es el ancho de banda, me gustaría que el programa obtuviera un mínimo de ancho de banda para poder funcionar correctamente con las peticiones, donde está instalado dicho programa tiene muchos ordenadores conectado en Red y absorben todo el ancho de banda, ¿alguna solución? muchas gracias.